# '14 Cruze Front Brake Noise

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, cruze

My '14 Cruze LT is making a funny noise when I hit the brakes, only when the car is in Park and only if the engine is running. They feel normal when driving. The noise is like it's hitting something underneath, and it sounds like it's coming from the front passenger side.

Comment: If you push the breaks hard, do you still hear it?

Comment: Get a recording of it?